# How to use workers with hypercorn serve?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, hypercorn

I want to start my FastAPI app using hypercorn from main.py.

I used this command to start the server manually:

`hypercorn --access-logformat "%(R)s %(s)s %(st)s %(D)s %({Header}o)s" --access-logfile - -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 9 app:app`

Now I need to do the same thing from my code. First attempt was:

```
from hypercorn.config import Config
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

from api.app import app # app = FastAPI()

config = Config()
config.bind = ['0.0.0.0:8000']
config.access_log_format = '%(R)s %(s)s %(st)s %(D)s %({Header}o)s'
config.accesslog = mainLog # mainLog = logging.getLogger('main')
config.loglevel = 'INFO'

asyncio.run(serve(app, config))
```

I've tried to set `config.workers = 9` , but in response I've got:

```
Warning: The config `workers` has no affect when using serve
  warnings.warn("The config `workers` has no affect when using serve", Warning)
```

Then I rewrite my code to this:

```
import logging
import asyncio

from hypercorn.config import Config
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

from api.app import app


mainLog = logging.getLogger('main')
...

async def main(app, config):
    await  serve(app, config)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    config = Config()
    config.bind = ['0.0.0.0:8000']
    config.access_log_format = "%(R)s %(s)s %(st)s %(D)s %({Header}o)s"
    config.accesslog = mainLog
    config.loglevel = 'INFO'
    config.worker_class = 'asyncio'
    config.workers = 9
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main(app, config))

    except:
        mainLog.exception('Fail to start server')
```

But I still got the same warning.
[Documentation](https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/how_to_guides/api_usage.html) says:

> ... it is possible to use Hypercorn programmatically via the serve function available for either the asyncio or trio Workers (note the asyncio serve can be used with uvloop).

Am I misunderstand the docs? I have lack of knowledge in this area, so please help me.

Answer (score 3):

There’s no out-of-the box functionality for this, although I can see how the documentation can be misleading. I made the same mistaken assumption about having to provide the config in a different format. That’s not the problem.

Multiple worker processes are supported if you run hypercorn as a standalone executable, as you mention you started out by doing. But they aren’t supported in any other configuration.

If you run hypercorn through its `serve()` API, the expectation is that *you* will implement the process management.

If you look in [`src/hyperhorn/run.py`](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn/-/blob/93e3c08c54c6de5ffdaaaed4e1b97aab4fcb7656/src/hypercorn/run.py#L15), you will see what Hypercorn does to implement multiple worker processes. You will need to replicate that in your code. So instead of something like `config.workers = 9`, you will need to create those processes yourself, and then within each process, set up their asyncio loops.